# Why function BCryptImportKey generate exeption?

Tags: c++, winapi, bcrypt

```
class Decrypt : Filefunc
{
public:
    Decrypt(std::string password)
    {
        fill_paths(paths);
        log.open("W:\\log.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
        szPass = new TCHAR[passphrase.size() + 1];
        copy(passphrase.begin(), passphrase.end(), szPass);
        szPass[passphrase.size()] = 0;
        std::ifstream iFkey("W:\\key.key", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
        
        status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider
        (
            &hAlg,
            BCRYPT_SHA256_ALGORITHM,
            NULL,
            NULL
        );
        log << test_status("BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider", status);

        status = BCryptGetProperty
        (
            hAlg,
            BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH,
            (PBYTE)&cbHashObject,
            sizeof(DWORD),
            &cbData,
            NULL
        );

        log << test_status("BCryptGetProperty", status);

        pbHashObject = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbHashObject);
        status = BCryptCreateHash
        (
            hAlg,
            &hHash,
            pbHashObject,
            cbHashObject,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL
        );
        log << test_status("BCryptCreateHash", status);

        status = BCryptHashData
        (
            hHash,
            (PBYTE)szPass,
            _tcslen(szPass) * sizeof(TCHAR),
            NULL
            );
        log << test_status("BCryptHashData", status);

        status = BCryptGetProperty
        (
            hAlg,
            BCRYPT_HASH_LENGTH,
            (PBYTE)&cbHash,
            sizeof(DWORD),
            &cbData,
            NULL
        );
        log << test_status("BCryptGetProperty", status);

        pbHash = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbHash); 

        status = BCryptFinishHash
        (
            hHash,
            pbHash,
            cbHash,
            0
        );
        log << test_status("BCryptFinishHash", status);

        

        status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider
        (
            &hAlg,
            BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM,
            NULL,
            NULL
        );
        log << test_status("BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider", status);

        status = BCryptGetProperty
        (
            hAlg,
            BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH,
            (PBYTE)&cbKeyObject,
            sizeof(DWORD),
            &cbData,
            NULL
        );

        log << test_status("BCryptGetProperty", status);

        pbKeyObject = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbKeyObject);

        status = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey
        (
            hAlg,
            &hKey,
            pbKeyObject,
            cbKeyObject,
            (PBYTE)pbHash,
            cbHash,
            NULL
        );
        log << test_status("BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey", status);


        iFkey.seekg(0, iFkey.end); 
        length = iFkey.tellg(); 
        iFkey.seekg(0, iFkey.beg); 
        impKeyBuf = new UCHAR[length];
        
        iFkey.read((char*)impKeyBuf, length);

         BCryptImportKey
        (
            hAlg,
            hKey,   
            BCRYPT_AES_WRAP_KEY_BLOB,
            &hKeyImp,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            impKeyBuf,
            length,
            NULL
        );

        log << test_status("BCryptImportKey", status);
    }
}
```

I am creating a program that encrypts all files on a USB flash drive. At the stage of importing the key, I get an exception that I can't analyze in any way. Exception text in the memcpy.asm file:

> `An exception was raised at 0x7C103B3F (vcruntime140d.dll ) in Zed_TEst.exe : 0xC0000005: violation of access rights when reading at 0x01010101.`

The `test_status` function simply returns a string in which the status of functions from bcrypt is written
when I try to display the status in the console I get something strange

> `output:` ╢
> ¶    ╖
> "     э$♦"♦`☼}☺╕
>      ♣  ♣╣
>     ║
> §     ь$☺§☺⌂♦╗
> a     ↕А♦a♦╝
> <     ь$♣<♣╜
> ▼     ь$♣▼♣1!.┐
> w     ☺w☺♦а     →ЁЖ☻└
> ¶     ☼¶☼☺┴
> ♦    ┬
>    ├ 
> ♥     ь$♣♥♣─
> ☺     ь$♣☺♣┼
>    ╞ 
>      ь$♣♣╟

Comment: `0x01010101` is clearly an invalid memory address to be reading from. You need to debug your code to find out where that is coming from

Comment: `iFkey.seekg(0, iFkey.end); 
        length = iFkey.tellg(); 
        iFkey.seekg(0, iFkey.beg);`  this part of my code just find a file length

Comment: Throws an exception on the line with the BCryptImportKey status output

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, read [ask] and take the [tour] as a new user here. Also, don't use C-style casts (they hide errors) and don't use `TCHAR`. There's more wrong with your code which may cause issues, but those are the parts that stick out.